# Perform SVN log without update

Tags: svn, logging

It seems that performing `svn log` gives me outdated information, unless I do an `svn update` first. But sometimes I don't want to update. Is there any way to get an up to date log (at least regarding my own commits) without updating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
svn log -r 1:HEAD /path/to/working/copy
```

Replace revision numbers to your liking.

```
Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                NUMBER       revision number
                                '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                                'HEAD'       latest in repository
                                'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                                'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                                'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
```

Comment: Thank you. I notice that this gives the newest entries at the bottom, not at the top like a reagular `log` does. Is that a bug or an oversight on my part?

Comment: @dotancohen: Use `svn log -r HEAD:1 /path/to/working/copy` for reverse order.

Comment: Using `svn log -r HEAD:BASE -l 10` will get you everything committed since your working copy.